# Merging 2 private sub VBA codes

Tags: vba, excel

i have 2 Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range) codes that work on their own. i need them to work in the same sheet. whenever i do this the 2nd code does not run. how do i merge these please!!?

Code 1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
     Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range([H2], Cells(Rows.Count, 
     "H").End(xlUp)))

     If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     rng.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",R1C[6] & ""-"" &" & 
     "TEXT(COUNTA(R2C[-1]:RC[-1]),""0000"") & ""-"" & R1C[7],"""")"
     Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Code 1 is using P1 and O1 to populate an automatic number in column I if information is provided in H 
Code 2:

```
Private Sub Move_blanks_To_Bottom(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 9 Then Exit Sub
    Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 11).Sort 
    key1:=Range("I1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Code 2 is using column I and sorting the values so if there is a value in I it move the row to the next available line where column I is completed effectively if cell I is blank the row is moved to the bottom.

as i understand you cannot run 2 private sub codes so how would i run both of these on the same sheet at the same time?

thanks!

Comment: Call the second `Sub` from the first one? Note that you don't typically "run" `Worksheet_Change` - it's an event handler.

Comment: Have you tried adding `DoEvents` at the end of `Worksheet_Change` event?

Comment: @Comintern when i call i get an error "Argument not optional" any idea on how to overcome this? my VBA is not amazing - thanks!

Comment: @Zac my VBA is not amazing do i just add DoEvents after Application.EnableEvents = True on the first code?

Comment: @DMO You need to pass the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Because your first code exits (`Exit Sub)` when it fails that `Intersect`, then you have to call your second subroutine above that `If` statement. You'll have to pass it the `Target` as well like:

```
 Call Move_blanks_To_Bottom(Target)
```

However, I think a rewrite might be best. Instead of exiting the subroutine all over the place, instead place relevant bits of code inside If statements so your routine can run to completion and exit gracefully:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Do logic for this first range
    Dim rng As Range
    rng = Range([H2], Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)))
    If Not Intersect(rng, Target) Is Nothing Then
        rng.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",R1C[6] & ""-"" &" & "TEXT(COUNTA(R2C[-1]:RC[-1]),""0000"") & ""-"" & R1C[7],"""")"   
    End If

    'now do logic for the second range (move_blanks_to_bottom)
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 And Target.Column = 9 Then
        Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 11).Sort key1:=Range("I1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes 
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for posting. i have entered the range for the first code but i am have trouble with the second range (VBA noob) wondering if you can help, the second code is looking in column I for values if there is a value there it moves to the next available line effectively pushing all blanks to the bottom its taking the whole row from A onward. im not to sure how to put this into the code. - thanks!

Comment: I like that you are doing that with Sort. Is the sort not working? If the blanks are ending up at the top, then perhaps just change that `xlAscending` to `xlDescending`. If that doesn't do the trick, I think this is worth of a new question.

Comment: so at the moment the only part working is the auto generation of the number. the sort doesn't work but i think this is partly because i am unsure how to set the range? your code asked me to include the second range but i am unsure how to define it?